# How to sort array in javascript using some static value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, node.js, sorting

```
let myArray = [{"title":"A", "name":"C"}, {"title":"B", "name":"C++"}, {"title":"C", "name":"Java"}, {"title":"D", "name":"Javascript"}, {"title":"E", "name":"Angularjs"}, {"title":"F", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"G", "name":"Express"}, {"title":"H", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"I", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"J", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"K", "name":"Angularjs"}, {"title":"L", "name":"Javascript"}, {"title":"M", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"N", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"O", "name":"C++"}];
```

Now I want to sort the above array like that:-
1. First, come Angularjs Data

2. Second, Come Nodejs Data
3. Third, Come Javascript Data

Then afterwards come according to array order

Required Output will be:-

```
[{"title":"E", "name":"Angularjs"}, {"title":"K", "name":"Angularjs"},  {"title":"F", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"M", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"N", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"D", "name":"Javascript"},
{"title":"L", "name":"Javascript"}, {"title":"A", "name":"C"}, {"title":"B", "name":"C++"}, {"title":"C", "name":"Java"}, {"title":"H", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"I", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"J", "name":"HTML"}]
```

My solution for doing this:-
 Loop through the array then after check the required condition, then place the matched value in new array. Similarly, I can get the desired output.

But it will require 4 loops
1 loop for Angularjs, 2nd loop for Nodejs, 3rd loop for Javascript, 4th loop for other values of array and the loop value might increase or decrease depending upon my static values

Comment: Also, *Angular/Node/JS* data? Please explain what you mean by that

Comment: I have already done by using loops as I mentioned in my answer but it is not the good way to solve the problem. So that's why I am posting the same @Rajesh

Comment: @ricky I have mentioned in the question

Comment: @Rajesh It means the array sorting take place according to Angularjs then nodejs and so on

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI I got it. There are `n` different ways to do it. If you share your current code(* it is not the good way*, hence you are here), it would be easier for us to help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a single loop:

```js
let myArray = [{"title":"A", "name":"C"}, {"title":"B", "name":"C++"}, {"title":"C", "name":"Java"}, {"title":"D", "name":"Javascript"}, {"title":"E", "name":"Angularjs"}, {"title":"F", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"G", "name":"Express"}, {"title":"H", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"I", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"J", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"K", "name":"Angularjs"}, {"title":"L", "name":"Javascript"}, {"title":"M", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"N", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"O", "name":"C++"}];
// create seperate array for angular, node and other
const ang = [];
const node = [];
const js = [];
const other = [];

myArray.forEach(function(v) {
  // push into array based on name
  if (v.name === 'Angularjs')
    ang.push(v)
  else if (v.name === 'Nodejs')
    node.push(v)
  else if (v.name === 'Javascript')
    js.push(v)
  else
    other.push(v);
})

// concat the arrays in the required order
const res = ang.concat(node, js, other);

console.log(res);
```

---

**UPDATE 1:** Using a multidimensional array instead of multiple variable:

```js
let myArray = [{"title":"A", "name":"C"}, {"title":"B", "name":"C++"}, {"title":"C", "name":"Java"}, {"title":"D", "name":"Javascript"}, {"title":"E", "name":"Angularjs"}, {"title":"F", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"G", "name":"Express"}, {"title":"H", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"I", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"J", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"K", "name":"Angularjs"}, {"title":"L", "name":"Javascript"}, {"title":"M", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"N", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"O", "name":"C++"}];
// create seperate array for angular, node and other
const temp = [[],[],[],[]]

myArray.forEach(function(v) {
  // push into array based on name
  if (v.name === 'Angularjs')
    temp[0].push(v)
  else if (v.name === 'Nodejs')
    temp[1].push(v)
  else if (v.name === 'Javascript')
    temp[2].push(v)
  else
    temp[3].push(v);
})

// concat the arrays in the required order
const res = [].concat(...temp);

// or [].concat.apply([], temp)

console.log(res);
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** Using an object reference for avoiding `if...else`:

```js
let myArray = [{"title":"A", "name":"C"}, {"title":"B", "name":"C++"}, {"title":"C", "name":"Java"}, {"title":"D", "name":"Javascript"}, {"title":"E", "name":"Angularjs"}, {"title":"F", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"G", "name":"Express"}, {"title":"H", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"I", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"J", "name":"HTML"}, {"title":"K", "name":"Angularjs"}, {"title":"L", "name":"Javascript"}, {"title":"M", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"N", "name":"Nodejs"}, {"title":"O", "name":"C++"}];

// create seperate array for angular, node and other
const temp = [
  [],
  [],
  [],
  []
];
const ref = {
  'Angularjs': 0,
  'Nodejs': 1,
  'Javascript': 2
};

myArray.forEach(function(v) {
  temp[v.name in ref ? ref[v.name] : 3].push(v);
})

// concat the arrays in the required order
const res = [].concat(...temp);

// or [].concat.apply([], temp)

console.log(res);
```

Comment: If this is the solution, should we not close the post with *how to sort array of object by property?*

Comment: @pranav you forget to add javascript in sorting

Comment: @Rajesh : if we had used normal sorting it wont maintain the order of ramaining .... ___`Then afterwards come according to array order`___

Comment: @PranavCBalan Correct. Took a while to realize it. +1